# Свойство View в элементе ListView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listview

В Winform у ListView есть свойство представления(View), которое можно поменять на значение Details для отображения данных в виде таблицы. Необходимо изменить это свойство в WPF. Только проблема в том, что  в WPF свойство View не имеет такого определения. Без этого свойства у данные в WPF выводятся в виде списка в один столбец

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Бросьте бяку, не используйте конструктор для такого! Выучите XAML и пишите все руками, очень сильно в дальнейшем вам это поможет. По поводу вопроса, почитайте например [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.9.php), там вы увидите, что в `ListView.View` заносится `GridView`, который имеет возможность отобразить все как таблицу.

Comment: Или вот еще [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865829/add-items-to-columns-in-a-wpf-listview).